# How can I get different values when reading the config register of an ADS1115 than I had written just before?

Tags: i2c, pigpio, analog-to-digital

I'm trying to read data from an ADS1115 ADC attached to the I²C link of my Raspi 3B using `pigpiod`, but get nothing. In order to pin down the error, I took a deep look at the config I write beforehand into the ADC's config register 0x01 to find out that the data, which are effectively stored in the register, are apparently not the ones I had sent to the device. This happens during the init of the device:

```cpp
int Initialize (int handle)
{
  int      ret            = 0;
  uint16_t adc_config     = 0;
  int      pigpiod_handle = handle;

  cout << "Initializing display and dimmer ADC...";

  i2c_handle = i2c_open (pigpiod_handle, 1, 0x48, 0);

  if (i2c_handle < (unsigned int) 0) {
    ret = errno;

    cout << "failed! Error: " << strerror (errno) << endl;
  }
  else {
    uint16_t reg = 0x0000;

    SetADCConfigBitfield (&adc_config, 0x8000, 0x8000); // Conversion: single.
    SetADCConfigBitfield (&adc_config, 0x5000, 0x7000); // Input: AIN1.
    SetADCConfigBitfield (&adc_config, 0x0200, 0x0E00); // Gain: ± 4096 mV.
    SetADCConfigBitfield (&adc_config, 0x0000, 0x0100); // Mode: continuous.
    SetADCConfigBitfield (&adc_config, 0x0000, 0x00E0); // Data rate: 8 samples / second.
    SetADCConfigBitfield (&adc_config, 0x0000, 0x0010); // Comparator mode: traditional.
    SetADCConfigBitfield (&adc_config, 0x0000, 0x0008); // Comparator polarity: active low.
    SetADCConfigBitfield (&adc_config, 0x0000, 0x0004); // Comparator latching: off.
    SetADCConfigBitfield (&adc_config, 0x0003, 0x0003); // Comparator queue: off.

    cout << "¤¤ " << std::bitset<16> (adc_config) << " ¤¤" << endl;
    ret += i2c_write_byte_data (vfd::pigpiod_handle, vfd::i2c_handle, 0x01, adc_config >> 8);
    ret += i2c_write_byte_data (vfd::pigpiod_handle, vfd::i2c_handle, 0x01, adc_config  & 0xFF);

    reg  = i2c_read_byte_data (vfd::pigpiod_handle, vfd::i2c_handle, 0x01) << 8;
    reg |= i2c_read_byte_data (vfd::pigpiod_handle, vfd::i2c_handle, 0x01);
    cout << "±± " << std::bitset<16> (reg) << " ±±" << endl;

    if (ret == 0) {
      cout << "done. Handle: " << vfd::spi_handle << "." << endl;
    }
    else cout << "ADC initialization failed! Error: " << ret << "." << endl;
  }

  return ret;
}

void SetADCConfigBitfield (uint16_t *config, uint16_t value, uint16_t mask)
{
  *config &= ~mask;
  *config |= (value & mask);
}
```

I took `SetADCConfigBitfield ()` and the various parameter values directly from [the driver written by Elektor Labs](https://github.com/ElektorLabs/ads1115-driver) (which I can't use because of incompatibilities). Here is the relevant part of my app's output:

```
Initializing display and dimmer ADC...
¤¤ 1101001000000011 ¤¤
±± 1000010110000101 ±±
done. Handle: 1.
```

As you can see, when I read the register immediately after writing, I get completely different data. What is the reason for this? Am I doing anything wrong?

**UPDATE** Here is the link to the datasheet. See pp. 28–29: [ADS111x datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1115.pdf?ts=1608869827939&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FADS1115)

Comment: refer to the datasheet ... never expect the read data to be the same as the written data,  unless the datasheet says so ... writing a control register and reading a status register involves two different registers even if both are at the same address

Comment: I have already read the datasheet, and it only says about bit #15 (the leftmost one) to have different meanings in write and read operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've found out what had been wrong here: the two [`i2c_write_byte_data ()`](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pdif2.html#i2c_write_byte_data) methods from pigpio. They send the following signals to the corresponding I²C slave:

```
Start Address WriteBit [A] Register [A] Payload [A] Stop
```

So, after the first byte has been written, a stop bit is emitted, followed by a start bit for the second byte. The ADC looks for a 2-byte value, not for two 1-byte ones.

In fact, [`i2c_write_word_data ()`](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pdif2.html#i2c_write_word_data) would have been the right choice, as this method writes both bytes in one operation. But: It writes the lower half-word (bits #7 to #0) first, followed by the upper half-word (bits #15 through #8). And this is not what the ADC wants, because it expects the upper half-word first.

My solution is to swap the upper with the lower half:

```cpp
reg = (adc_config << 8) | (adc_config >> 8);
ret = i2c_write_word_data (vfd::pigpiod_handle, vfd::i2c_handle, 0x01, reg);
```

Now everything works.

Comment: Thank you for posting this.  The reversed order in i2c_write_word_data had completely escaped me, and once I saw this everything worked in a program I was doing.